# Scripting Elasticsearch 2.1| No such property: doc

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, scripting, aggregation, elasticsearch-2.0

I am facing an issue while trying to execute a script within an ES JSON request

The request:

```
POST _search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "match_all": {}
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "bucket_histogram": {
         "histogram": {
            "field": "dayTime",
            "interval": 10
         },
         "aggs": {
            "get_average": {
               "avg": {
                  "field": "value"
               }
            },
            "check-threshold": {
               "bucket_script": {
                  "buckets_path": {
                     "averageValue": "get_average"
                  },
                  "script": "averageValue - doc[\"thresholdValue\"].value"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But I get this error instead of returning values

```
    {
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [],
      "type": "reduce_search_phase_exception",
      "reason": "[reduce] ",
      "phase": "fetch",
      "grouped": true,
      "failed_shards": [],
      "caused_by": {
         "type": "groovy_script_execution_exception",
         "reason": "failed to run inline script [averageValue - doc[\"thresholdValue\"].value] using lang [groovy]",
         "caused_by": {
            "type": "missing_property_exception",
            "reason": "No such property: doc for class: 7dcca7d142ac809a7192625d43d95bde9883c434"
         }
      }
   },
   "status": 503
}
```

Yet if I remove doc[\"thresholdValue\"] and enter a number everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `bucket_script`, which is a part of the [pipeline aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html) released with Elasticsearch 2.0. Pipeline aggregations work against other aggregations and not documents, which is why the `doc` context is not supplied to the aggregation.

If you want to process aggregations against specific documents, then perhaps you want the [scripted metric aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer.
I was hoping to implement this in java yet I can't find any documentation for bucket scripting java api.
Do you happen to have any useful links?

Comment: Here's the [Java API documentation for aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_structuring_aggregations.html). It doesn't show pipelines, but the structure is the same.